# Issue while playing video selected from ALAssetLibrary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I get the URL from Asset and try to play selected video.But `MPMoviePlayer` do not show anything

```
     NSString* urlStr =  @"assets-library://asset/asset.mp4?id=0685B109-8699-410D-8775-140972AF8397&ext=mp4";
     NSURL* movieUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr];
     MPMoviePlayerController* player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    [player view].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeDefault;
    player.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;

    [player setContentURL:movieUrl];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];

    [player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [player play];
```

And i get in console:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2013-12-11 15:47:17.575 XavBookXavient[74716:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2013-12-11 15:47:17.583 XavBookXavient[74716:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2013-12-11 15:47:17.583 XavBookXavient[74716:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2013-12-11 15:47:17.587 XavBookXavient[74716:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the following method.

```
[player prepareToPlay];
```

Calling "prepareToPlay" fixed your problem, Without it, "MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification" was not being sent because the player didn't bother to preload the video.